# Angular 2 Unit test Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RequestOptions'

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular, jasmine

I want to test a simple component that have some Dependencies. So among others I have to provide some providers.

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, provide } from '@angular/core';

import {
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  inject,
  fakeAsync,
  TestComponentBuilder
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { LogoutButtonComponent } from './logout-button.component';
import { UserService } from '../../services/index';

describe('Component: LogoutButtonComponent', () => {

  let component: LogoutButtonComponent;

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    LogoutButtonComponent,
    Http,
    provide(AuthHttp, { useFactory: Http }),
    provide(AuthConfig, { useValue: new AuthConfig() }),
    ConnectionBackend,
    RequestOptions,
    UserService
  ]);

  beforeEach(inject([AuthHttp, UserService, LogoutButtonComponent],
    (comp: LogoutButtonComponent) => {
      component = comp;
    }));

  it('should inject UserService', () => {
    // My test here
  });

});
```

Though I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RequestOptions'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RequestOptions' is decorated with Injectable.

Am I missing something oin the `beforeEachProviders` function?

Note: This question is related only with the Unit Testing of Angular 2  with Jasmine. I'm not searching infos relate bootstraping app as this is already ok in my app and there are other related questions here.

Answer (score 24):

You have to import `HttpModule` into your TestBed configuration.

```
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule
  ]
});
```

After that unit testing should work

Comment: This is the only solution which works for the newest Angular 4 where `beforeEachProviders` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

`RequestOptions` is not an injectable, you don't inject this into classes. Instead, you instantiate one as needed when making an HTTP request. So you can remove it from the `beforeEachProviders`, and instantiate one in the `beforeEach` if you actually need it in the tests:

```
let options: RequestOptions;

beforeEach(inject([AuthHttp, UserService, LogoutButtonComponent],
    (comp: LogoutButtonComponent) => {
      component = comp;
      options = new RequestOptions({method: RequestMethod.Post});
}));
```

Comment: Hi @Sunil, in this case I'm getting:
`Error: No provider for RequestOptions! (AuthHttp -> RequestOptions)`

Comment: @VassilisPits where are you getting that error? Somewhere you are trying to inject `RequestOptions`, and you should not be doing that. 1) You cannot inject this class, it does not have the `Injectable()` annotation, check the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L17-L123). You just need to instantiate the `RequestOptions` object w/the `new` operator as shown above, and as shown in the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html).

Comment: I'm not injecting somewhere else, that's the strange thing :/

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed my error by importing `HttpModule` and `Http` from `@angular/http` :

```
import {HttpModule, Http} from "@angular/http"; 
...

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpModule], // <!-- HTTP module
  providers: [HttpService, SourceService, Http] // <!-- HTTP
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to mock out the user service then you don't have to worry about the RequestOptions or the HttpModule, here's my approach to problem above:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LogoutButtonComponent } from './logout-button.component';
import { UserService } from '../../services/index';

describe('Component: LogoutButtonComponent', () => {

  let component: LogoutButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LogoutButtonComponent>;
  let mockUserService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Provide array of user service methods used in LogoutButtonComponent to the createSpyObj
        mockUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['exampleUserServiceMethod']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ LogoutButtonComponent ],
            providers: [
                { provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService }
            ],
            // Only if your component uses routing
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LogoutButtonComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

    })

  it('should inject UserService', () => {
    // My test here
  });

});
```